# Initialize static generic list in constructor

Tags: c#, list, generics

Is this not possible? I get

> T is not valid in this context.

```
public static class SQLDynamicData<T>
{
    public static List<T> SQLDataList;

    static SQLDynamicData()
    {
        SQLDataList<T> = new List<T>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need the first `<T>` in the assignment:

```
SQLDataList<T> = new List<T>();
```

Should be:

```
SQLDataList = new List<T>();
```